# Dataplex Explore Workbench how is works?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, data-lake, google-dataplex

i´m trying to run some data exploration via Dataplex Explore workbench, however i can´t pass this first page: [image: dataplex explore tab]

i have created a Lake, Zone and Assets:
[image: dataplex manage lake tab]

also a Dataproc Metastore cluster:

[image: dataproc metastore]

and 'default' env for the lake:

[image: default env]

but the explore tab is still the same.

my project is in europe-west1 and is conected to host project via Shared VPC.

any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add an assets (GCS buckets or BQ datasets) under Lake/zone hierarchy. The assets will get discovered and you should be able to see tables discovered from the GCS buckets and BQ datasets in Explore tab.